# Setting std::shared_ptr source at a later stage

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm just starting out with C++ and trying to get my head around smart pointers. Obviously, the following code will crash (I suppose it's because the assignment created a copy of the shared_ptr?). Is there a way to keep `foo.Other` updated by calling some kind of set method on `ptrs[3]`?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int X;
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> Other;

    Foo() : X(10) { }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> ptrs(10);

    foo.Other = ptrs[3];

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> other = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());
    ptrs[3] = other;

    std::cout << foo.Other->X << std::endl; // throws Access violation exception

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
This is the exception I'm getting since it's pointing to null:

> First-chance exception at 0x01219AEF in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
>   Unhandled exception at 0x01219AEF in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: One thing you should definitely be doing is using `std::make_shared` instead of `std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that doing this:

```
foo.Other = ptrs[3];
```

creates some sort of relationship between the two objects so that if you change one of them then the other also changes.

That's not how `shared_ptr` works.  The thing it *points to* is shared, and changing that thing means all the pointers to it see the changed value (because there's only one value, which is owned by multiple objects) so this works:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>(1);
assert( *p == 1 );
std::shared_ptr<int> q = p;
*q = 2;
assert( *p == 1 );
```

But the shared_ptr objects themselves don't all start being identical copies of each other.

They *point to* the same thing, that doesn't mean they *are* the same thing.

If you change `ptrs[3]` to point to something different that doesn't also make `foo.Other` point to something different.  If it did that would make `shared_ptr` almost useless, you couldn't usefully have multiple owners of an object, because as soon as one of them stopped owning the object all the others would stop owning it too and it would be destroyed.

Instead only the `shared_ptr` you update gets a new value, other `shared_ptr`s keep their old value.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>(1);
assert( *p == 1 );
std::shared_ptr<int> q = p;
assert( *q == 1 );
assert( p == q );
assert( p.get() == q.get() );
assert( *p == *q );
p = std::make_shared<int>(2);
assert( *p == 2 );
assert( *q == 1 );
assert( p != q );
assert( p.get() != q.get() );
assert( *p != *q );
```

Comment: +1, this *pointer* vs *pointed-to* stuff was so "obvious" I didn't even think about mentioning it, my bad. Good explanation BTW. :)

Comment: @syam and Jonathan: Looking at this question after taking a break I feel pretty stupid. I was under the impression that I need to pass the pointers around by reference which somehow lead to this strange constelation. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 3):

Irrelevant of `shared_ptr` and other stuff, all your code boils down to:

```
int a = 0;
int b = a;
a = 42;
// why b isn't == to 42?
```

Think about it for a second... I'm afraid that's as much an answer as I can provide.

Don't hesitate to ask for clarification, I'll gladly answer, but before you do please think about it *again*.

Comment: Thanks syam, in this case `b` should only hold a reference to `a` if we are expecting `b` to equal `a`. I'll fiddle around a bit with my example.

Comment: Ok, I'll clarify: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> ptrs(10);` creates a vector of 10 empty `shared_ptr`. You assign one of those empty `shared_ptr` (what I called `a`, you call it `ptrs[3]`) to `foo.Other` (what I called `b`). Then you change `a`, and expect `b` to change? ;) There are no references here, you're just copying values.